# What is somebody who can "predict" or "see" into the future called?

Tags: single-word-requests

I always make intuitions regarding the future, sometimes good and sometimes bad, and most of the time they are likely to be proven true. So what would a person be called whose intuitions always become true and happen?

Comment: A psychic or a clairvoyant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  And yes clairvoyant is a nice word but it doesn't fit to my context like it seems having supernatural power to see future is clairvoyant (Clear-Site) but its a bit strong for my case. But still I liked this word. Cheers

Comment: Also, IMO, Visceral-(adj.) obtained through intuition

Comment: Clairvoyant is really someone who can see hidden things in the present, not necessarily in the future.  'Seer' works here.  'Prophet' would too, but there's often a religious implication.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In such a case you are ***prescient***.

[prescience](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prescience)

> noun pre·science \ˈpre-sh(ē-)ən(t)s, ˈprē-, -s(ē-)ən(t)s\
>
> the ability to know what will or might happen in the future

Comment: Yeah this one suits perfectly 

Answer (score 3):

Although the word "**prophet**" may have a religious meaning in some contexts, it can also be used to refer to a person with non-spiritual abilities to predict the future.

[prophet](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/prophet)

> A person who makes or claims to be able to make predictions: 
>   
>  *the anti-technology **prophets** of doom* (Oxford Dictionaries)

Answer (score 3):

A person who has:

> Foreknowledge of an event, especially as a form of extrasensory perception. (ODO)

is **[precognitive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/precognition)** (adjective):

> *The woman who stepped into my office was tall, leggy, beautiful - and bewildered, "How did you know I was about to knock" "Like it says on the door, I'm a precognitive detective.*

Jack Hammett, [Precognitive Detective](https://books.google.rs/books?id=zHUSBgAAQBAJ&pg=PP1&dq=precognitive&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=precognitive&f=false)

or has precognitive abilities/ability of precognition:

> *"He's been dead for ten years", she said.*
>
> *"Er", said Windle, but the question was already there in his larynx, "I trust Mr. Cake is in good health?"*
>
> *"It's okay. Oi speaks to him occasional," said Mrs. Cake.*
>
> *"I'm sorry to hear that," said Windle.*
>
> *"All right, if it makes you feel any better."*
>
> *"Um, Mrs. Cake? I'm finding it a little confusing. Could you...switch off...your precognition...?"*

from: [The Reaper Man](https://books.google.rs/books?id=GjIkBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT149&dq=precognition+the+Reaper+man&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=precognition%20the%20Reaper%20man&f=false), by Terry Pratchet

(context: Mrs. Cake has the ability of precognition, so she answers Windle's questions before he has the chance to ask them.)

Answer (score 1):

There is the word **prognosticator** which according to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/prognosticator) means *one who predicts future events or developments* and defined by [Lexico (powered by Oxford)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/prognosticator) as *a person who foretells or prophesies a future event*. Although it sounds quite rare, I quite like it and the questioner has not specified if they want a rare word or a common word. Google Ngram gives a spike between 1580 and 1600 and then there's a decline in its use. But it has been in use since 1730s until now.

Answer (score 0):

If it is true, you are a foreseer:

> FORESEE''R, n. One who [foresees](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=foresee&use1828=on) or [foreknows](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=foreknow&use1828=on).

If you believe the gift is somehow divine in nature, then you are an [Oracle](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=oracle&use1828=on).

Reference: [Noah Webster's American Dictionary of the English Language, 1828](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Another word you could use is **augur**.

From [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/augur):

> noun
>   1. one of a group of ancient Roman officials charged with observing and interpreting omens for guidance in public affairs.
>   2. soothsayer; prophet.
> verb (used with object)
>   3. to divine or predict, as from omens; prognosticate.

A synonym of augur is **auspex**.

Also, **predictor** is someone who predicts.

Answer (score 0):

How about **visionary**?

OD:

> [**visionary**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/visionary): A person with original ideas about what the future will or could be
>   like